# Custom csv file upload

Tags: c#, csv

I need to create a method that gets the uploaded csv file and add the data from the file and adds it to the table.

I am using C# and InterBase.

The problem that I have - some users can upload different format of the csv (so I cant create a hard coded class). There are 10 columns and 4 of them are mandatory. User can upload a file with 4 columns or more. So I need to match the name of the columns from the file with the columns from the table. Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Will the column names in the source file **always** match the column names in the destination table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done fairly easily. You can choose to do it from scratch or leverage existing tools to this. Basically, you need to read the data from the CSV into a DataTable or a custom object. Then in turn you can write that table or object to the database.

I recommend you take a look at the CSV Helper -
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

CSV Helper should do everything you need to do, except write to InterBase. Try to avoid reinventing the wheel unless you have to.

But, if you really want to write your own from scratch you can do so. Typically my first step is to load the data from the CSV file into a DataTable. Then I create the custom objects and build a list of them. This is because I usually already have a way of writing the custom objects to the database/final destination.

The mapping of columns from a DataTable to your object should not be hard because you can refer to a column by its name. Here is a very basic example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable CarsImportedFromFile = new DataTable();
        // load data in from CSV
        List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>();

        foreach (DataRow CurrentRow in CarsImportedFromFile.Rows)
        {
            Car MyCar = new Car();
            MyCar.Model = CurrentRow["Model"].ToString();
            MyCar.Color = CurrentRow["Color"].ToString();
            Cars.Add(MyCar);
        }
    }
}

class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

There are many ways to do all of these things. If you search SO you can find good questions on dynamically mapping, data to object conversion, importing CSV, etc.

Comment: thank you I've tried a simple solution and it's working great.